# Is it better to use braces or no braces for single-line if blocks?

Tags: c#, if-statement, braces

What is better coding practice for single-line code blocks following an if statement - braces or no braces?  Just to avoid too many "Well, it depends on what language you're using..." answers, let's say for C#.  In other words, which is better:

```
if(somecondition)
{
  singleLineStatement;
}
```

Or

```
if(somecondition)
  singleLineStatement;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the consensus is to use braces. If you omit the braces there is a risk that someone will add an extra line without noticing the missing braces.

Comment: I make my `if` and `else` match. If the `if` is multiline and the `else` is single, they'll both be bracketed. If I have two single line components in the `if` and `else`, then they'll both generally* be sans-braces. I don't feel the need to completely idiot-proof the code, because they keep making better idiots.  (*) There are exceptions if braces help readability, such as when a single statement spans multiple lines.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I tend to do that as well. The hardcore support for superfluous braces I occasionally encounter is quite humorous.